# Openbox won't load wallpaper on startup

Tags: x11, openbox

I've tried a lot of things. I googled and followed tutorials and I'm still unable to have my wallpaper load on startup.

What I've done so far is I've added the wallpaper of my choice via feh

`feh --bg-scale /home/MYNAME/Pictures/wallpaper123.jpg`. This set's my wallpaper just fine.

Obviously after restart, the wallpaper is not loaded. So I followed some tutorials that had me do the following

I added this code  `#My wallpaper eval cat $HOME/.fehbg &` to the `autostart.sh` file in  `/etc/xdg/openbox`.

Well, when I restart, my wallpaper is never loaded.

I also tried adding a directory called "Wallpapers". I then copied the following code

```
 #!/bin/env bash
 WALLPAPERS="/home/yourUserName/wallpapers"
 ALIST=( `ls -w1 $WALLPAPERS` )
 RANGE=${#ALIST[@]}
 let "number = $RANDOM"
 let LASTNUM="`cat $WALLPAPERS/.last` + $number"
 let "number = $LASTNUM % $RANGE"
 echo $number > $WALLPAPERS/.last

 feh --bg-scale $WALLPAPERS/${ALIST[$number]}
```

into a file called `wallpaper.sh` and saved it at `~/.config/openbox/`

I ran `chmod +x wallpaper.sh`

and added

```
#Random wallpaper
./pathFromHome/wallpaper.sh
```

to my `autostart.sh` file.

Still, nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `~/.config/openbox/autostart` (without `.sh`) it is executed as a shell script on startup (doesn't need `+x`)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I was making was creating the `wallpaper.sh` file in `~/.config/openbox/`

I should have only created a file called `autostart.sh` or `autostart` (either work for me) inside `~/.config/openbox/` and in that file I simply write `feh --bg-scale /home/myusername/Pictures/nameOfPicture.png`

I then save and close. After restarting, the wallpaper of my choice is displayed at startup.

**EDIT**

Very important..

Do not forget to add `&` at the end of script, like I did just now.

So the updated `autostart` should look like this

`feh --bg-scale /home/myusername/Pictures/nameOfPicture.png &`

Forgetting to do so means that when openbox starts, it will execute the above but without the `&` that might be the only thing it executes and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong; very wrong. Do not create any exec scripts.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/openbox#Wallpaper_.2F_background_programs

Comment: Oh shoot. Is it because I forgot to add `&` at the end?

I've reviewed what you linked a few times and the only discrepancy with the link's use of `feh` is the `&` at the end of the `autostart` file. 

I remember reading about how it's important to have that or otherwise everything else will not execute without the `&`.

I will fix this right now. If there is anything else that I'm doing wrong, please let me know and if you can, more specifically.

Thank's a lot.